# I need to know what happens in this code

Tags: php

I am learning PHP and still, I'm at a basic level.I got a code,

`echo "2>5-",2>5, "\n";`

I can't understand what happens here.

If anyone can help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

echo prints stuff into the page. “2>5-“ is a string. So, echo prints “2>5-“ to the page. With echo, you can concatenate using the comma (,) symbol. Although, it is more common to concatenate (that is, join two strings together) using the dot (.) symbol.

The second 2>5 is not enclosed in quotes. This indicates it is a boolean expression. In PHP,  the boolean value false is casted to an empty string ( “”). So, the result of 2>5 is false, which is converted to an empty string.

Lastly, the “\n” string indicates an escape character designating the start of a new line.

So, in summary, the expression `echo "2>5-",2>5, "\n";`will output “2>5-” followed by a newline character which has no visual representation. So, you will only see “2>5-” when you run that program.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to explain

```
echo "2>5-",2>5, "\n";
```

Echo prints out stuff, it's what it does.

- `"2>5-"` is a string and is output
- with echo you can use `,` instead of `.` for concatenation.Personally I never use it.
- `2>5` is not a string, it's comparison operation.  Is 2 greater then 5, the answer is `false`, and when echoing `false` PHP just outputs nothing or at best an empty string which is essentially nothing.
- `"\n"` is a new line, or a line return, which ever way you prefer to say it.

And that is it, you wind up with

```
2>5-
\n //which you can't see, unless you print more "stuff"
```

Answer (score 2):

**echo "2>5-",2>5, "\n";**

Outputs:

```
 2>5-
 \n <-- // hidden
```

**,** used by the `echo` to concatenate strings

**String 1** - "2>5-" output - `2>5-`

**String 2** - 2>5 - comparison which results to FALSE, therefore prints nothing. If TRUE prints 1.

**String 3** - "\n" - output - a `new line`.

Comment: echo is not a function you can test this with `array_map('echo', [1,2,3]);` which gives us `function 'echo' not found or invalid function name`.  Just saying, don't take it the wrong way, we will use the term "function" loosely for it ... lol  ... by the way neither are `empty`,`isset` or the `include/require`  "functions".  I believe they are "language constructs" which sounds way worse then function.

Comment: Updated answer. Still a function to me tho, just labeled differently.

Comment: Like I said it no big deal, really.  Just most people don't realize that...  But I am not most people.  Cheers!